# How to approach this multithreading task, problems with logical structure

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I have two ICs which convert sensor signals connected to a Raspberry Pi:

- IC1 sends his data every 2 seconds as a serial telegram.
- IC2 is an ADC that sends its data after receiving a certain control signal.

I have written separate codes that let me extract the measurement values out of the serial telegram as well as request and receive the ADC values and they are both working fine on their own. However, they are blocking my main program and I want to have the sensor values at the same time. Additionally, while waiting between serial telegrams I'd like to constantly sum the ADC's output and when the telegram is received, an average value for the analog data should be calculated.

At the moment, my average value calculation is performed like this:

```
class ADC():

    # [...]

    def startAvg(self):
        self._recording = 1
        interrupt = threading.Thread(target=self.stopAvg())
        recording = threading.Thread(target=self._record())
        recording.start()
        interrupt.start()
        return self._avgs

    def _record(self):
        sum1 = 0
        sum2 = 0
        counts = 0
        while self.recording:
            sum1 += ADC[0] # ADC channel 0
            sum2 += ADC[1] # ADC channel 1
            counts += 1
        self._avgs = [ sum1 / counts, sum2 / counts ]

    def stopAvg(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        self._recording = 0
```

I created a dummy function that just sleeps (stopAvg) to simulate the arrival of a serial telegram. Later, the averaging should be stopped from outside the class, in my main program. However, even now, _record() is only called *after* stopAvg() is finished. Where's my mistake? I have read some tutorials about threading, but I don't see how to apply it on my problem, especially the averaging. I know it could simply get my tasks done one after the other but I want to get the average value so that peaks in my signal are taken care of. Are threads the right solution after all?

I think I just need a good advice on how to structure my threads since I never worked with threads before.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake:

```
interrupt = threading.Thread(target=self.stopAvg())
recording = threading.Thread(target=self._record())
```

The brackets inside target's argument don't belong there!

```
interrupt = threading.Thread(target=self.stopAvg)
recording = threading.Thread(target=self._record)
```

...is how it should be.